# Not able to change keys in JavaScipt dictionary

Tags: javascript, dictionary, key

I am a beginner, I want to replace spaces with hyphen from keys of JavaScript dictionary and get the keys back in dictionary

eg. In `nameVars = {"my name is":"aman", "age":22, "my ed":"btech"}`
I want resultant dictionary to be, `nameVars = {"my-name-is":"aman", "age":22, "my-ed":"btech"}`  I am doing it using

```
for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(nameVars)){
  key.replace(/\s+/g,"-")`
}
```

But my output is still same keys are not changing, please help I don't know JavaScript.

Can someone tell what changes to make if instead this it is in format

`topicMessage = { topic: 'some_topic', messages: [{ 'myKey': '{"data": {"my name is ":"aman", "age": 22, "my ed": "btech"}, "meta": {"myAge":24, "school":"aps"}}' }, { 'myKey2': '{ "data": { "my name is 2": "aman", "age": 22, "my ed 2": "btech" }, "meta": { "myAge2": 24, "school": "aps" } } ' }, { "myKey3": '{"data": {"my name is 3":"aman", "age": 22, "my ed 3": "btech"}, "meta": {"myAge":24, "school":"aps"}}' } ] }`

here inside messaages of topicMessages in data part we have to make keys dash separated, and value for mykey, mykey2, mykey3 are in string form, so need to convert JSON.parse to object first and then again convert it back to string.

Comment: `.repalce` returns the replaced content .. it doesn't replace content - also, you can't change the key like that

Comment: Using a sentence as an object key seems a little unwieldy. Why can't it just be `{ name: 'Aman'...}`?

Comment: @andy It is actually not sentace actual code has keys such as "version name", and i want to replace spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace the content of the Object

```
var nameVars = {"my name is":"aman", "age":22, "my ed":"btech"}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(nameVars)) {
  if(key.includes(" ")){
    const newKey = key.replace(/\s+/g,"-")
    nameVars[newKey] = value;
    delete nameVars[key]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @MatthewSaintball, sir is there a way to keep order of key value pair intact, I am getting {age:"" , 'my-name-is', 'my-ed'}, could it be {"my-name-is", "age" , "my-ed"} as it previously was.  Again thank you, and sorry for asking silly questions.

Answer (score 1):

You modify the names of the keys but never add the modified keys back to to the object. You can approach your problem like this:

```js
for(const [oldKey, value] of Object.entries(nameVars)){    
    const newKey = oldKey.replace(/\s+/g,"-");
    // add the entry with the new key
    nameVars[newKey] = value;
    // delete the old entry
    delete nameVars[oldKey];
}
```

Comment: Hello @DieterRaber thank you for this answer, I am extremely greatly for you quick and effect answer I just have a doubt, your is deleting values for which there is no space hence not modified eg : "age":22.           . Again I am grealy thankful.

Comment: @AmanKandari you might consider accepting this as the correct answer then.

Comment: You're right about that, Aman, this is something I hadn't considered. @matthewsaintbull's answer is better than mine.